# Flyway is not executing script

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

I have Spring Boot application with Flyway.

I have following sql script:

`src/main/resources/db/migration/V1__init.sql`

but the script is not executed.

In `application.properties` file I have:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/carorderprocess?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.username = root
spring.datasource.password = ...
spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true
```

When I run application, in DB I only see:

```
mysql> select * from flyway_schema_history;
+----------------+---------+-----------------------+----------+-----------------------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+
| installed_rank | version | description           | type     | script                | checksum | installed_by | installed_on        | execution_time | success |
+----------------+---------+-----------------------+----------+-----------------------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+
|              1 | 1       | << Flyway Baseline >> | BASELINE | << Flyway Baseline >> |     NULL | root         | 2019-11-19 10:47:52 |              0 |       1 |
+----------------+---------+-----------------------+----------+-----------------------+----------+--------------+---------------------+----------------+---------+
```

So the script is not executed, why?

Comment: Have you tried to migrate using `flyway migrate` command?

Comment: no. how do i do that

Comment: try in console, where your `pom` file located, to run `mvn flyway:migrate` command.

Comment: I know it is not your case, but I also didn't get the V2 migration working and the problem was that my V2 file had only 1 underscore instead of 2: `V2_Migration` (wrong) instead of `V2__Migration` (correct)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This script won't run, as the version of the filename provided is not higher than the greatest version stored in `flyway_schema_history` table. There are two solutions you can do:

1. Clear the `flyway_schema_history` table
2. Rename your file to `V2__init.sql` (recommended solution)

Then simply restart your spring boot app, and changes should be applied out of the box

One note: 1st solution probably requires removal of `spring.flyway.baselineOnMigrate = true` property. I would also consider if you really need it. What it does can be found [here](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/migrate)

Comment: New link to the [baselineOnMigrate documentation](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/configuration/configfile) which explains why solution #2 works.

Answer (score 0):

When you create Spring Boot application using Flyway, you need to do the next steps:

First. Add flyway dependency in `pom.xml`, if using maven:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.flywaydb</groupId>
    <artifactId>flyway-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.3</version> 
</plugin>
```

Second. Generate `flyway.properties` file and it should reside in the same directory as the `pom.xml` file. Default configs to describe:

```
flyway.user=databaseUser
flyway.password=databasePassword
flyway.schemas=schemaName
flyway.url=jdbc:h2:mem:DATABAS
flyway.locations=filesystem:db/migration
```

Third. Create your migration files under `db/migration` folder. For example - `V1_1_0__my_first_migration.sql`.

Fourth. Run the application: `mvn spring-boot:run`.